# Raspberry Pi to Computer - Scripted File Transfer and Deletion

Tags: bash, shell-script, raspberry-pi, raspbian, transmission

This is my first ever Bash script and I've done the best I could to find most of the answers on my own, but I have finally come to a road block.

This script seems to (mostly) work, but I am not receiving the files on my iMac's side of things.

The idea here is having a dedicated RPi torrent box with auto-file xfer to main computer followed by directory/file cleanup on the RPi system for space saving.

This script appears to handle any directory and/or file thrown at it, spaces and such do not affect its ability to initiate SCP.

I need a review of syntax by someone experienced in Bash scripting to find my error. Here is my script in its entirety. Any offers to increase efficiency would be greatly appreciated.

Updated with corrections used so far.

Narrowing issue down: `select_target_directory` function
Did I do this `target_directory_selected=` part correct? Not sure this variable is being filled.

```
#!/bin/bash

# variables declared
directory_on_localhost="/mnt/32gb_pny_usbdrive/completed/*"
directory_on_remote_host_primary="/Volumes/Drobo/zIncoming"
directory_on_remote_host_secondary="/Users/josh/Desktop/zIncoming"
target_directory_selected=""

# functions defined
# This function basically verifies the Drobo is mounted on the iMac.
select_target_directory () {
    if [ 'ssh josh@10.0.1.2 test -d /Volumes/Drobo/zIncoming' ]
    then
        target_directory_selected="$directory_on_remote_host_primary"
    else
        target_directory_selected="$directory_on_remote_host_secondary"
    fi
}

# This function copies target <directories/files> to the target directory (via scp)
# and then deletes them from the local machine to conserve valuable storage space.
process_the_files () {
    for current_target in $directory_on_localhost
    do
         scp -r "$current_target" josh@10.0.1.2:"$target_directory_selected"
         rm -rf "$current_target"
    done
}

# main logic begins
# [Tests "$directory_host" for contents] && [iMac status (i.e. powered off or on)]
# IF "$directory_host" is not empty AND iMac is powered on THEN functions are invoked
# And Main Logic is completed and script ends, ELSE script ends.
if [ "$(ls -A $directory_on_localhost)" ] && [ 'nc -z 10.0.1.2 22 > /dev/null' ]
then
    select_target_directory
    process_the_files
else
    exit
fi
# main logic ends
```

Comment: There are several inconsistencies in your variable names. You define `directory_on_remote_host_primary` but use `$directory_remote_primary` that you did not define. Am I wrong?

Comment: Also: 1) Instead of `[ 'ssh josh` you probably mean `[ $(ssh josh…) ]` same with `nc` later 2) Quote your variables: `josh@10.0.1.2:"$target_dir"` 3) You don't need bash here, a `#!/bin/sh` will do just fine and is more portable.

Comment: Renaud - I definitely missed that, sigh. I probably shouldn't rename variables as much as I did making this. So good catch and thank you.

Comment: Marco - I tried running this as #!/bin/sh but it wouldn't execute, so changed back for now. Please help me understand the difference between `'ssh josh'` versus `$(ssh josh`

Comment: Why are you using either ``[ `command` ]`` or `[ $(command) ]` to get the return value of `command`? How would you handle the case when `command` is `echo -z aaa`? Simply using `command` is enough and sane. If you want to throw away the output, well, use `command >/dev/null`.

Comment: P.S. `[ the-only-argument ]` tests if the argument is a non-empty string, therefore your `[ 'ssh` line is always true.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 - Again folks, first script ever here...learned from [this bash tutorial](http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/) just a few days ago. May I presume you understand via context my goal? What then is the solution to enable my understanding, thanks.

Comment: Welcome back to the site. While I find the effort you present to comply with community rules commendable, I wonder if any _specific_ feedback from contributors and/or moderators has convinced you to take such a "preemptively defensive" stance as expressed in your opening notice (which seems rather drastic to me). If you feel you have been incorrectly treated, you may want to flag offending comments to attract moderator attention, or open a post on [U&L Meta](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/) to clarify the issue.

Comment: @AdminBee - I've got thick skin. Nothing specific apart from my discovery of the content in Tour and Asking. Observe the comments above; the knowledge gap is real! I'm simply putting myself out there to be taken seriously, genuinely, and earnestly. I don't want to be perceived as some troll. Much syntax to learn I have. </visible engagement> lol

Comment: I think you are safe there, otherwise your post would have attracted (a lot of) downvotes. I would consider it safe (and actually recommend) to remove the opening statement from your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

> ```
> if [ 'ssh josh@10.0.1.2 test -d /Volumes/Drobo/zIncoming' ]
> then
>     target_directory_selected="$directory_on_remote_host_primary"
> else
>     target_directory_selected="$directory_on_remote_host_secondary"
> fi
> ```

You probably meant this:

```
if ssh josh@10.0.1.2 test -d /Volumes/Drobo/zIncoming
then
    target_directory_selected="$directory_on_remote_host_primary"
else
    target_directory_selected="$directory_on_remote_host_secondary"
fi
```

Note that `[ 'non-empty string' ]` is always true. You probably wanted to use a condition on the `ssh` command, the way I rewrote it for you.

Similarly, later in the script you probably want to replace `[ 'nc -z 10.0.1.2 22 > /dev/null' ]` with `nc -z 10.0.1.2 22 > /dev/null`.

Comment: I've been away a long while and have now returned (from/to scripting & tinkering) to find an old question answered. By reading between the lines and interpreting what I was trying to accomplish and then fixing my code you make the process of understanding that much clearer. Thank you!